# How to get the position of a view inside the page in xamarin/maui?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, maui

I'm trying to create a listview selector and I want the Listview to show itself on the top of the view which shows the selected item, when it is placed at the end of the page. if it is at the end of the page, then the user is not able to access the list when he clicks the selected item.

[image: list when we click on selecteditem]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Name="ComboBoxView"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference ComboBoxView}"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.ComboBoxNew">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*" >
        <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="5" CornerRadius="0" BorderColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnDefinitions="75*,25*" >
                <Label Text="{Binding Source={Reference ComboBoxView}, Path=SelectedItem }" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                <ImageButton Source="arrowdown" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" ></ImageButton>
            </Grid>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OpenListItemsClickedEvent" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ComboElementsList" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowDefinitions="Auto,*" >
            <Image Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" Source="arrowup" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ></Image>
            <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={Reference ComboBoxView},Path=ItemSource}" Unfocused="ListUnfocusedEvent" x:Name="ComboListElements" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="0" Padding="15" HasShadow="True" BorderColor="Gray">
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="ItemSelectedFromListViewEvent" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>


using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class ComboBoxNew : ContentView
{
    public ComboBoxNew()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboListElements.Opacity = 0;
        ComboElementsList.Opacity = 0;
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: ItemSourceChangedEvent);

    public ObservableCollection<string> ItemSource
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItem", typeof(string), typeof(string), string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public string SelectedItem 
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    private void OpenListItemsClickedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboListElements.FadeTo(1, 500, Easing.Linear);
        ComboElementsList.FadeTo(1, 500, Easing.Linear);
        var Xitem = ComboListElements.X;
        var Yitem = ComboListElements.Y;

    }

    private void ListUnfocusedEvent(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboListElements.FadeTo(0, 500, Easing.Linear);
        ComboElementsList.FadeTo(0, 500, Easing.Linear);
    }

    private void ItemSelectedFromListViewEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedValue = ((e as TappedEventArgs).Parameter) as string;
        SelectedItem = clickedValue;
        ComboListElements.FadeTo(0, 500, Easing.Linear);
        ComboElementsList.FadeTo(0, 500, Easing.Linear);
    }

    private static void ItemSourceChangedEvent(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (bindable is ComboBoxNew comboBoxNew && newValue != null && newValue is ObservableCollection<string> newItemSource) 
        {
            comboBoxNew.SelectedItem = newItemSource.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Shared, please check

Comment: Sorry Venky, I cannot exactly catch what you mean. Seems that you could use a popup when clicking the item and you could place it as you want.

Comment: You could refer to [Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup) for more information

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT In the Image, there's a list, and if i tap on any of the items like "New Value 0,1,2,3" etc, then it updates the dropdown which is above the list and once tapped the list collapes and just shows the selected item from the list, I want to get the position of this control I've created with respect to the page it is a part of, so that if it is at the bottom of the page, I would place the list on the top instead of bottom, so that the user sees the entire list and not a part of it. I hope I'm making sense

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can't you just order the XAML so the elements are in desired order, top to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I thought you want to change the position of the **ComboBoxNew ContentView**. You might set the Translation of it when UI changes. Just like the following code:

```
mycontrol.TranslationY = -100; //  other values could be set
```

And **ComboBoxNew ContentView** will move up and show the item.

Hope it works for you.